# Renaming multiple files using a loop

Tags: linux, files, rename, mv, for

I need to rename some files using a loop but I can't get it to work as I am still very new at Linux. the files that need to be renamed are:

```
E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.10.fa  
E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.16.fa  
E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.21.fa  
E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.7.fa
```

to a shorter name such as:

```
E9.bin.10.fa
E9.bin.16.fa
E9.bin.21.fa
E9.bin.7.fa
```

I have used `rename` and `mv` and other loops I've seen in threads but still cannot get it to work. any input is much appreciated! thank you!

Comment: why do you need to use a loop? ... also, please add your attemped code to your post

Comment: I have over 78 samples in one of my directories that need to be renamed, but I have got it! using the following: for file in *.fa; do E23="${file/-GOWN186_multiplemap/}"; mv -- "$file" "$E23"; done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have perl `rename` (default on Ubuntu, Debian and many other systems), you can just do

```
rename -n 's/-GOWN33_multiplemap//' ./*fa
```

If that gives you the right file names, run without the `-n` to actually rename them:

```
rename 's/-GOWN33_multiplemap//' ./*fa
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
for f in *.fa; do 
  echo mv -- "$f" "${f%-*}.${f#*.}"
done
```

Result:

```
E9.bin.10.fa
E9.bin.16.fa
E9.bin.21.fa
E9.bin.7.fa
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all those files are in the current directory, and that all of them, and no other files, match the globbing pattern

```
E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.*.fa
```

Then, you may loop over these with

```
for name in E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.*.fa; do
   # more code here
done
```

Inside the loop, `$name` will be the name of one of these files.

Given the name `E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.10.fa` in `$name`, we can remove the `E9-GOWN33_multiplemap` bit from the start of the name with

```
${name#E9-GOWN33_multiplemap}
```

It's then just a matter to re-attach the initial `E9` string to the front of that to create `E9.bin.10.fa`:

```
newname=E9${name#E9-GOWN33_multiplemap}
```

With `mv` we may then rename the old filename to the new:

```
mv "$name" "$newname"
```

So, with that we have

```
for name in E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.*.fa; do
    newname=E9${name#E9-GOWN33_multiplemap}
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

or shorter,

```
for name in E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.*.fa; do
    mv "$name" "E9${name#E9-GOWN33_multiplemap}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```bash
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(*)-GOWN33_multiplemap(.bin.<->.fa)' '$1$2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for f in *.fa; do mv -- "$f" "${f/-*p./.}"; done
```

- input:

  ```
  E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.7.fa
  E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.10.fa
  E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.16.fa
  E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.21.fa
  ```
- output:

  ```
  E9.bin.7.fa
  E9.bin.10.fa
  E9.bin.16.fa
  E9.bin.21.fa
  ```

you aslo can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the directory path where the files are located
directory="/path/to/files"

# Loop through the files in the directory
for file in "$directory"/E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.*.fa; do
    # Extract the original filename
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    
    # Extract the numeric part from the original filename
    number=$(echo "$filename" | awk -F'.' '{ print $3 }')
    
    # Create the new filename
    new_filename="E9.bin.$number.fa"
    
    # Rename the file
    mv "$file" "$directory/$new_filename"
done
```

In this script, the for loop iterates over the files matching the pattern E9-GOWN33_multiplemap.bin.*.fa in the specified directory. Inside the loop, the original filename is extracted using basename. Then, the numeric part is extracted using awk. Finally, the new filename is constructed by combining the fixed parts (E9.bin.) with the extracted number. The mv command is used to rename the file with the new filename.